Deriving an analytical solution for a bar under distributed torsion
Okay, so I'm considering the torsion model given by this figure:

I understand that the differential equation of such bar model is given as:
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\left[G(y)J(y)\frac{\text{d}\theta_y}{\text{d}y}\right]=-m_y(y)$$
The boundary conditions for this differential equation are $\theta_y(0) = 0$ (no rotation at the clamped end), and $GJ \frac{\text{d}\theta_y}{\text{d}y}(L) = 0$, meaning no twisting moment at the free end (consider that the bar has length $L$). Considering that the distributed moment is given as $m(y) = -m_{y0} \cdot y$, in which $m_{y0}$ is a fixed value, solving this equation leads to:
$$\theta_y(y) =-\frac{m_{y0}y}{2GJ}\left(\frac{y^2}{3}-L^2\right)$$
The integration process I carry out is the following:

Assuming $GJ$ as constants, then the first integral would result: $GJ \frac{\text{d}\theta_y}{\text{d}y} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot m_{y0} \cdot y^2 + c_1$
The second integral results in $GJ \theta_y = \frac{1}{6} \cdot m_{y0} \cdot y^3 + c_1\cdot y + c_2$
From the first boundary condition ($\theta_y(0) = 0$) : $c_2=0$
From the second boundary condition ($GJ \frac{\text{d}\theta_y}{\text{d}y} (L) = 0$) : $c_1 = \frac{1}{2}GJ \cdot m_{y0} \cdot L^2$

However, I'm almost 99% sure I'm making some mistake somewhere, because this answer does not reflect what I'd expect. What am I getting wrong here? Any ideas?

It seems like one mistake is in the last step, $c_1$ should be $-m_{y0}\cdot L^2$.

I did not go through your work.
We start with the twist $d\phi$ in a small differential length $dy$ and then integrate, removing the $\frac{1}{GJ}$ outside because it's a constant.
I use $\tau_y$ for your annotation $m_y$
$$ d\phi= \frac{ \tau_y*dy}{GJ}= \frac{1}{GJ}( \tau_y *dy)$$
we need to express $tau$ as a function of y.
$$\tau=\tau_y*y$$
$$\phi=\frac{1}{GJ} \int_0^L  \tau_y*y *d y \\ \phi=  \frac{1}{GJ}\biggr\rvert_{0}^{l} \tau_y\frac{ y^2}{2} $$

For a cantilever shaft subjects to uniformly distributed torque, I think the differential equation should be:
$\dfrac{d}{dy}[GJ\dfrac{d\theta_y}{dy}] = -m_o$, $m_o$ denotes torsion per unit length (force-length/length)
Integrate the equation once and we get
$GJ\dfrac{d\theta_y}{dy} = -m_oy + C_1$
Apply the boundary condition $\dfrac{d\theta_y}{dy} = 0|_{y=L}$
$GJ\dfrac{d\theta_y}{dy}|_{y=L} = -m_oL + C_1 = 0$, solving and yields $C_1 = m_oL$
PLug $C_1$ into the equation and Integrate again, we get
$GJ\theta_y = -m_o\dfrac{y^2}{2} + m_oLy + C_2$
Apply boundary condition $GJ\theta_y = 0|_{y = 0}$, which yields $C_2 = 0$
Plug $C_2$ into the equation, we get the general equation
$GJ\theta_y = -m_o\dfrac{y^2}{2} + m_oLy = m_oy(L-\dfrac{y}{2})$
